# Is there a way to turn off horizontal scrolling in an iPad?

Tags: ipad, horizontal-scrolling

I like to read with a guide finger sweeping across the page when using an ereader app ... Kind of difficult with horizontal scrolling between each swipe :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. You can try reading with a glove on. Granted it can't be the fancy ones that lets you use your ipad/iphone/touchscreen device with them on.